# Create Document Library using REST API in C# on Client Machine [Not in SharePoint Server]

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, visual-studio

I am working on a requirement where I need to create Document Library using REST API using C# code using Visual Studio.

The main problem is that I am not having SharePoint Server environment. I am just having site URL and credentials.

When I use following code to get the data from list item then that works properly. But now I want to create document library. So can any one suggest what should I change in my code so that it can create a document library. I tried various codes with **POST** but that are of no use for posting here.

My **GET** code is as follow:

```
SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "Password".ToCharArray())
                passWord.AppendChar(c);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("SiteURL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=id,LastName");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", passWord, "siteurl");
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials();

        //Read the returned posts into an object that can be consumed by the calling application
        using (response)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                try
                {
                    string jSON = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("An error occurred when reading the list items from SharePoint: {0}; {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this using the Client Object Model would be much easier. Unless you have a reason that you absolutely need to use the REST API, I suggest you switch.

That said, here's the code you need to create a list using the REST API:

```
private ICredentials creds = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

private string GetFormDigest()
{
    var url = siteUrl + "/_api/contextinfo";
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = creds;
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] =
        "application/json;odata=verbose";
    var json = client.UploadString(url, "");

    var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic item = ser.Deserialize<object>(json);

    var digest = item["d"]["GetContextWebInformation"]["FormDigestValue"];

    return digest;
}

private void CreateList()
{
    var digest = GetFormDigest();

    var url = siteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists";
    var body = "{'__metadata': { type: 'SP.List' }, " +
        "BaseTemplate: 107, " +
        "Title: 'Tasks'}";

    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = creds;
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] =
        "application/json;odata=verbose";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] =
        "application/json;odata=verbose";
    client.Headers["X-RequestDigest"] = digest;
    var json = client.UploadString(url, body);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sample code to create document library .

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists

method: POST

body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 101,

 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My list description', 'Title': 'Test' }

Headers: 
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-length:length of post body
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks but I have this, I need from c# calling REST API using C#.